# Problem in downloading "ToMatLab" package

Tags: functions, packages, custom-notation

Iam trying to download "ToMatLab" Package from 
http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/
but it is showing me an error message by showing a big question mark and "File could not be loaded" "Try refreshing the page". Iam using windows 7 premium operating system.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't left-click on the download symbol, as this will try to open the file inside your browser (using the *Mathematica* plugin). Right-click on the download symbol and save the file on your PC.

Comment: Thank you so much.. Such a silly mistake i was doing from two days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but it is not working

The above does not describe the problem you are having. When you say not working, you need to explain how it is not working, and what you tried.

I just downloaded it and I see no problem.  Using V10.01, on windows. Downloaded it from http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/

Here are some examples

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
<< ToMatlab.m
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Clear[x, y];
expr = Sin[x]*Cos[y];
ToMatlab[expr]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol = y[x] /. First@DSolve[{y'[x] == x, y[1] == 1}, y[x], x]
(* 1/2 (1 + x^2) *)
ToMatlab[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And this is an example from the notebook that comes with the package

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So it seems to "work".   How exactly it is it not working for you?

Comment: when i try to download it is showing me a symbol of a big question mark saying that "File could not be loaded" , "Try refreshing the page". i did it many times but isn't not working. I tried using mozilla and google chrome. My OS is windows 7 premium.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps MatLink is an alternative solution.

http://matlink.org/